# Viewing $\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}$ as an eigenvector of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, ring-theory, representation-theory, definition

It's easy to see that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}.$$

So in some sense, the function $\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta \\ \sin \theta\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$.

> **Question.** Is there an accepted definition of the term "eigenvector" in ring theory or representation theory, generalizing its usual meaning, such that this is actually true?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true since 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is itself a linear operator. Vector $\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
$ is an eigenvector of the operator
$$\partial_{\theta}-\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
With the corresponding eigenvalue zero.

Comment: This is such a half-arsed answer...